# Error(24,66): PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm making a trigger that checks if a person can go to a world or European championship, and if they go by car, calculates how much they spent on fuel(fuelcost * spends * distance/100). I need to put that info in another table but I'm getting this message:

```
Error(24,66): PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
```

That's because I've put "fuelcost * spends * :new.distance/100" in INSERT statement at the bottom of code. My question is, how can I put that value in table costs in some different way. Column costs.money is not calculated column because it's not just fuel costs in that table, so that isn't a solution.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_norm_fuel_cost 
  INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE ON insert_travel_view
  FOR EACH ROW
  DECLARE 
    hasnorm char(1);
    spends number;
    fuelcost number;

  BEGIN
    SELECT norms.norm INTO hasnorm
      FROM norms JOIN competitions
        ON competitions.competitionID=norms.competitionID
      WHERE :new.personID = norms.personID 
           AND (competitions.name LIKE 'European championship' 
              OR competitions.name LIKE 'World championship');

      IF hasnorm = 'Y' OR hasnorm IS NULL THEN
        INSERT INTO travel(travelID, personID, competitionID, vehicleID, distance) 
          VALUES (:new.travelID, :new.personID, :new.competitionID, :new.vehicleID, :new.distance);
        IF :new.distance IS NOT NULL THEN
          SELECT vehicles.consumption INTO spends FROM vehicles 
            WHERE :new.vehicleID = vehicles.vehicleID;
          SELECT fuels.cost INTO fuelcost FROM fuels JOIN vehicles ON vehicles.fuelID = fuels.fuelID
            WHERE :new.vehicleID = vehicles.vehicleID;

          INSERT INTO COSTS(costID, costtype, travelID, money)
            VALUES(35, 'fuel', :new.travelID, fuelcost*spends*:new.distance/100);

        END IF;
      END IF;
  END;
```

Comment: Is `distance` in the calculation the final insert supposed to be `:new.distance` ?

Comment: Yes, but it's not solving this error. I think that the problem that INSERT cannot get arithmetic expression in VALUES

EDIT: I edited code in question.

Comment: That is the problem though you have two others - did the error message change when you added the `:new:` ?

Comment: No unfortunately, it's still the same. If it was just :new. I would probably get it myself. What two other problems are you talking about?

Comment: Well, with dummy tables it works OK with the `:new` for me. The `(24,66)` points to the line and character number (counting `declare` as line 1), which points to that `distance` reference too, give or take. Please add the schema DDL (all six tables, and the view) to the question so we can recreate the problem. If you're changing names for posting, make sure you're doing it consistently.

Comment: Did you change insert statement values to subquery?

Comment: Expressions in the `values` list are perfectly normal, they are not the cause of the error.

Comment: Can you add a description of your view and the tables that appear in the trigger?

Comment: Did your problem solved ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change explicit values in the insert statement to 
select like insert into(...) select .... from , sorry for bad formatting writing from mobile.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I mean change insert into() values(); with insert into tablename () select your_col_list from tablename where clause .

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have three issues; the ORA-00984 is because your final insert is doing:

```
VALUES(35, 'fuel', :new.travelID, fuelcost*spends*distance/100);
```

where the `distance` is being interpreted as a column name, because there is no variable in scope with that name; it should presumably be:

```
VALUES(35, 'fuel', :new.travelID, fuelcost*spends*:new.distance/100);
```

although you could avoid the `spends` and `fuelcost` local variables and do an `insert ... select` instead:

```
INSERT INTO COSTS(costID, costtype, travelID, money)
SELECT 35, 'fuel', :new.travelID, fuels.cost*vehicles.consumption*:new.distance/100
FROM fuels JOIN vehicles ON vehicles.fuelID = fuels.fuelID
WHERE vehicles.vehicleID = :new.vehicleID;
```

You also have what appear to be two typos:

```
    INSERT INTO travel(travelID, personID, competitonID, vehicleID, distance)
```

is missing an `i` and should (I think) be:

```
    INSERT INTO travel(travelID, personID, competitionID, vehicleID, distance)
```

and:

```
        WHERE :new.vehicleID = vehicle.vehicleID;
```

is missing an `s` and should (I think) be:

```
        WHERE :new.vehicleID = vehicles.vehicleID;
```

Comment: Thanks, those two typos were made when translating names od variables from Croatian to English, they're fine in my code.